# Drawing an SVG Selection Box with Batik

Tags: svg, batik

I notice on many SVG builder tools that almost each element can be resized and rotated. As shown below

[image][image]

What is the most common way to implement that whenever an element whenever is clicked, a bordering line will appear a long side with the small rectangles used for resizing as well as rotating ?

Are these objects "hidden" by default and only visible during mouse click ? Or they have to be drawn on every `mousedown` and removed on every `mouseup` ?

Comment: Is this specifically for batik or are you talking about generic SVG selection boxes?

Comment: I am using Batik. But I believe the procedures are similar in general. Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are these objects "hidden" by default and only visible during mouse
>   click ?

Unless you're using a library that provides that functionality i.e [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/manage-selection), then no you have to draw that selection rectangle yourself.

---

All the tools you see floating around essentially have code somewhere to create this rectangle you see exactly on top of the selected item - this rectangle is called the visible [Bounding Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) of the element - in modern browsers this is fetched using the [`el.getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method.

The returned bounding box gives you all the information you need(`x`, `y` , `width`, `height`) to draw that *selection rectangle* yourself.

Typically you have a canvas on which you work (might be a `<div>`, might be an SVG rectangle etc...) - the concept is not exclusive to HTML5 canvas.

- You draw the selection rectangle when clicking an *element*.
- You remove the selection rectangle when clicking on a canvas empty area.

Here is a snippet I've made for this which also allows multi-selection by holding 'Shift'.

```js
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'

// Draw selection box if we click on one or more elements.
$('.element').click(function() {
  const bbox = $(this)[0].getBBox()

  if (shiftKeyDown) {
    drawSelectionRect(bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height)

    return
  }

  $('.selectionRect').remove()
  drawSelectionRect(bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height)
})


// Remove selection box(es) if we click on empty area.
$('#svgCanvas').click(() => {
  $('.selectionRect').remove()
})


// Helper function which draws a selection box.
const drawSelectionRect = (x, y, width, height) => {
  var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect')
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x)
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y)
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', height)
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', width)

  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '2px')
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'red')
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none')
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-dasharray', '5,1')
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'selectionRect')

  document.getElementById('workarea').appendChild(rect)
}


// Determine if Shift key is being pressed.
let shiftKeyDown = false

$(document).keydown(e => {
  if (e.keyCode == 16) {
    shiftKeyDown = true
  }
})

$(document).keyup(e => {
  shiftKeyDown = false
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: block;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.element {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Click on any element to draw it's selection box.</li>
  <li>Hold down "Shift" to allow multi-selection.</li>
  <li>Click anywhere else on the canvas to remove selections.</li>
</ul>

<div id="container">
  <svg  id="workarea" width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect id="svgCanvas" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" style="fill:transparent"/>
    <rect class="element" width="100" height="100" x="50" y="100" style="fill:#009688;" />
    <rect class="element" width="75" height="100" x="250" y="150" style="fill:#009688;" />
  </svg>
</div>
```